# How would you convert this swf file to run as an app on iOS(or to fully function the way it does now)?

Tags: iphone, flash, ipa, file-conversion

I stumbled upon this developers marvelous PipBoy iOS app, and was eager to see it finished so I could get a copy and fulfill my dream of owning it. However, he's been silent for a long time, but posted this preview here http://www.seanzook.com/Pip-Boy/Z_Pip-Boy_App_v02.swf

I instantly loved it and tried for many hours to convert it or at least get it fully functioning on my iPhone 4s, to no avail. I was wondering if there's anyway to get it working on my iPhone without using a flash browser so I can have it offline also.

Is there any way it can be converted into an .ipa file?
Can I get it to play on my device? (I am jailbroken and tried iSWFPlayer and it doesn't run correctly).

I would be really happy to have this amazing piece of work, but am completely uneducated on how or if it can be done. If someone could help, I would appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a Flash project that loads the SWF into itself, and exporting the Flash project to AIR for iOS, yielding an .ipa.

http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2012/12/ios-apps-flash-cs6.html
http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Actually it takes just a few minutes to convert Flash SWF game file into iOS IPA application package using [Andaired](http://www.lovershorizon.com/2013/04/andaired.html)

Answer (score 0):

Great website! I don't know how to port swf to ipa. There is another solution gaf file: texture atlas + config file.
Have you tried GAF converter? I would recommned this tool for you. It is designed to manage, convert and store flash animations. I have been  using GAF to create my iPad game with Starling library. But they also support Cocos2d-x and Unity3d.